# Meteor Reactjs owl Carousel

Tags: reactjs, meteor, owl-carousel

This is my main component that i am render av from the mini mongo db.
 My current issue is when I send this.props.av into the carousel it does not load. I did notice that the props is only visible after some the component re-renders itself. In the displayAvCarousel if I pass avCarouselList array The carousel will work no problem. But one I change from the static array to the array from the backend there is an issue with loading the carousel. I am not sure what the issue may be. I was thinking the data is not loading with the component on mount. Any suggestions.  Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import AV from './AV';

class FullAVList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  }
  displayAvList() {
    let avList = this.props.av;

    return avList.map((av) => {
     return <AV key={av._id} av={av} />;
    });
  }
  // filter sponsored events
  displayAvCarousel(){

    const avCarouselList = [
      {
        id: 1,
        img: "./images/av-img-header.jpg",
        s: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        img: "./images/av-img-header.jpg",
        s: true,
      },
    ];


    let avFilters = this.props.av.filter((av) => av.s == true);

    return this.props.av.map((av) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <img src={av.img} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel showArrows={true} legend={false} showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} swipeable={true}>
          {this.displayAvCarousel}
        </Carousel>
        {this.displayAvList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('autoevents');

  return {
    av: AV.find({ av: true }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),
  };
}, FullAVList);
```

Comment: Two things to try: {this.displayAvCarousel} -> {this.displayAvCarousel()} (add brackets).  And createContainer is deprecated, you should be using withTracker https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker

Comment: Thanks man, i think that might be it.

Answer (score 0):

Let your displayAvList function receive an argument of the array from props. The reason nothing is showing is because when the component renders no props has arrived yet.

```
 render(){
 const {av} = this.props;
   // av represents your array which you can pass to the 
    // function displayAvList
 return (
    Carousel showArrows={true} legend={false} 
     showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} swipeable= 
    {true}>
      {this.displayAvCarousel}
       {this.displayAvList(av)
    </Carousel>

 })}
```